# Regex: grab the string that begins after a certain string and ends when it hits any other character

Tags: regex, azure, substring, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to use Regex to grab a substring of a large string. 
The overall string has certain text, 'cow/', then any number of characters or spaces that are not digits. The first digit hit is the start of the desired substring I want. 
This desired substring consists of only digits and periods, the first character or space seen that is not a digit or period indicates the end of the desired substring.

For example: 
'cow/ a12.34 -123'

The desired substring is '12.34'.

So far I have this regex that partially works (I think the '| .' is not entirely correct):
**(?<=([A-z]|[0-9])/\s*).*?(?=\s*[^0-9 |.])**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @knittl, I'm trying to make this language independent, so I figured the regex would need to do all the work :)

Comment: You don't need OR like that, this: [a-z]|[0-9] will be equal to: [a-z0-9]

Comment: Though if it helps, I am working in Azure Kusto.

Comment: @Adam: I've extended my answer to include an example for how to extract capturing groups from a regex with Azure Kusto.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to achieve by relying on capturing groups:

```
cow/[^0-9]*([0-9.]+)
```

The group will contain the text that you want to extract, in Java `group(index)`, in C# with `Groups[index]`. Other languages provide similar features.

Don't try to solve everything inside the regular expression, but leverage the power of your runtime :)

---

Edit after comment on the OP:

Azure Kusto has the [`extract(regex, captureGroup, text [, typeLiteral])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractfunction) function to extract groups from regular expression matches:

```
extract("cow/[^0-9]*([0-9.]+)", 1, "cow/ a12.34 -123") == "12.34";
```

The argument `1` tells Kusto to extract the first capturing group (the expression inside the parentheses).